# TensorFlow: Unable to feed the same placeholder twice in the same session

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I defined a placeholder - X  of shape ( None , 100)

In one session of tensorflow:

- I fed the placeholder with an input of (64,100) and Trained my Model
- Now when I again want to input a (3,100) matrix to the placeholder but it shows an Error here saying :

> ERROR : Cannot feed value of shape (3, 100) for Tensor
> u'RNN-LM/zeros:0', which has shape '(64, 100)'

Comment: The operations on the placeholder must assume that the input is of the shape (64,100). Are you using a static recurrent neural network? More detailed code would be helpful.

Comment: It says you're feeding the value of a zeros tensor, not a placeholder. Example code would help.